# Change Value of text file using java and save over the file using changed value

Tags: java

So basically I am writing an Application like inventory. 
For instance, 
If there are inventory of..

A) Guavas - 5
B) Apples - 2
C) Oranges - 3
D) Bananas - 1
E) Kiwi - 9
F) Quit

(in the txt file)
then I would like the user to change the value of inventory like

What would you like to do? A add 2
...

What would you like to do? B remove 1
...

What would you like to do? E add 1
...

What would you like to do? F

And then Make it save txt file as the changed value..

Comment: Where is your code? and what's the problem?

Comment: I suggest: Use `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines()` or `.lines()` to read the file when your program starts up. Use `String.split()` to separate the text (Guavas) from the amount in stock (5) and `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the amount to `int` (for calculations). On quit, use `Files.write()` to write the file back. You may do the same after each operation so work is saved in case of a crash. Happy coding.